# Create new column with loc() iloc() and apply after using groupby see pictures

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Given this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import requests
import pandas as pd
  
URL = "https://boards.4chan.org/x/archive"
  
HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',\
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
  
webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))

threads = dom.xpath('//tbody/tr')[0:2]
print(len(threads))
threads_count = 0
rows = []

for i in threads:
  thread_ids = i.xpath('.//td[1]')

  for j in thread_ids: 
    thread_id = j.text

    threads_count += 1 
    print(f"Currently checking ID = {threads_count}/{(len(threads))}", end="")
    url2 = (f'https://boards.4chan.org/x/thread/{thread_id}')
    webpage = requests.get(url2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
    dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))

    threads_containers = dom.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"Container")]')

    for x in threads_containers:
      post_id = x.xpath('.//span[@class="postNum desktop"]/a[@title="Reply to this post"]')[0].text
      content = x.xpath('.//blockquote[@class="postMessage"]/descendant::text()')
      
      new_content = []
      for el in content:
        if thread_id in el:
          el = el+" (OP)"
          new_content.append(el+"\n")
        else:
          new_content.append(el+"\n")

      rows.append([thread_id, post_id, ''.join(new_content)])

    print("\r", end="")

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Threads IDs', 'Posts IDs', 'Content'])
df
```

I get a the following DF (**yours can be different because it scraps "live" archives**):

[image]

Then I use this code:

```
df1 = df[['Threads IDs', 'Posts IDs']].groupby('Threads IDs').count().rename(columns={'Posts IDs': 'Number of Posts'})
df1
```

to get the following result:

[image]

Now, what I would like, its creating a third column named "What", applying the code below but for the entire dataframe:

```
df.loc[df['Threads IDs'] == '31904499', 'Content'].iloc[0]
```

I tried to play with "apply" and the code above, without success.

**If I resume:**
After using "*groupby*" to get the new DF with the "*Number of Posts*" by "*Threads IDs*", I would like to create a third column, named "What", which contains for each row the first value of "Content" ([0]) corresponding to the respective "Thread ID".

Answer (score 0):

This will group the dataframe by `'Threads IDs'` and show the first row for each group

```
df.groupby('Threads IDs').first()
# Out: 
#              Posts IDs                                   Content
Threads IDs                                                             
# 31886119     31886119  Are Greys simply humans from the future? \nIf ...
# 31901943     31901943  In the video game Event 0, one of the main thi...
```

To get a dataframe with counts and the content of the first post for each thread:

```
df
#         Threads IDs Posts IDs                                            # Content
# 0      31886119  31886119  Are Greys simply humans from the future? \nIf ...
# 1      31886119  31886125  >>31886119 (OP)\nYou don't even know if 'Greys...
# 2      31886119  31886142  Probes for higher concious beings. They attach...                                               ...
# ..          ...       ...
# 173    31901943  31904460  >>31902625\n>The moment the replikas started t...
# 174    31901943  31904484  >>31902874\nDo it, Oblivion is always the game...

df.groupby('Threads IDs').agg(['count', 'first'])['Content'] \
  .rename(columns={'count':'Number Of Posts'}) \
  .reset_index()
# Out: 
#   Threads IDs  Number Of Posts                                              first
# 0    31886119              147  Are Greys simply humans from the future? \nIf ...
# 1    31901943               31  In the video game Event 0, one of the main thi...
```

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I want. If you re-read my question (check second picture and my footnote), second column need to be "Number of Posts".

Comment: @drakax you can always merge 2 dfs, the answer of of user2314737 gives you the first comment per ID, exactly what you asked for

Comment: @NoobVB well ok I guess, BUT what if i would like the third one? This is why I would like to elaborate/extrapolate with "df.loc[df['Threads IDs'] == 'x', 'Content'].iloc[0]" and .apply() to entire DF, to have a more flexible solution for further scraps :)

Comment: @user2314737 Thank you :) I will validate your answer but what if I would like NOT the first but the second or third or nth value? Should I create a new question? Or modify this one? Or wait a little bit? Sorry. I'm still pretty new as you can see ;)

Comment: @drakax I would say post a new question

Answer (score 0):

After digging stackoverflow a little bit more, I've finally found exactly what I wanted:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Threads IDs')
df2 = df1.agg({'Posts IDs':'count'}).join(df1['Content'].nth(3)).fillna('Not enough data.').rename(columns={"Posts IDs": "Number of Posts"})
df2
```

This code offers more flexbility.

Result:

```
             Number of Posts                                                 Content
Threads IDs                                                              
31909432                   8       >>31909432 (OP)\nTypical toxic white chud. \nT...
31910606                   2                                        Not enough data.                                    Not enough data.
```

This code let me chose whatever nth() value I want from 'Content' and print the text I want when there's not data available.